# How to identify what event triggered a github webhook (pr, push, issue etc)

Tags: github, github-api, webhooks, githooks

Looking at the [docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestevent), each event has a "Webhook event name", but that doesn't seem to be sent in the payloads of the webhooks.

If you create a webhook that listens to multiple events, how (besides duck typing) would you be able to differentiate which event was the one that triggered the hook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the header `X-GitHub-Event`, as documented [here](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#delivery-headers)